# How do I check if none of the values in the array are empty?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Is there a shortcut to check if none of the values in the array are empty. I don't want to have to list it out one by one.

```
$form_inputs = array (
    'name' => $name,
    'gender' => $gender, 
    'location' => $location,
    'city' => $city,
    'description' => $description);

if (!empty(XXXXXXXX)){
        echo 'none are empty';
    } else {
        header('Location:add.school.php?error=1');
        exit();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
if(in_array('', $form_inputs)) {
  echo 'has empty field(s)';
}
```

`in_array` will recognize `''`, `null`, `0`, `false` as empty, so it may not work too well, depending on your values. This is typically good for checking string arrays.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (has_empty($form_inputs)) {
    // header location
}

function has_empty($array) {
    foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
        if (empty($value)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think des's answer is more targeted to this use case.."none of the values in the array are empty". I think the OP wanted to make sure that none of them are empty. Rather than a foreach, searching for '' should do the trick.

Comment: @AyeshK I agree, I would go with des's solution.

Comment: Just make it an function (e.g. `has_empty($array)) and I'll give +1

Comment: @des I thought of that at first, but then your answer appeard and I realized yours was a better solution so I didn´t bother. I have updated my answer now though.

Comment: well, my solution has some flaws (which I have pointed in my answer), but someone may check this in future and find your solution better :)